# Python Imbedding a variable into a excel formula

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

My method of using my DAY variable into a string formula is not working properly.
This method of using a variable in SQL queries and file paths a massive amount of times, however I can't figure out why its not now.

SOLVED by encasing the string in """ ---  """

```
date = '09-13'
DAY = int(date[3:])
templateFormula = f'=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&'Ref Sheet'!$A$1:$A${DAY}&"'!$E$2:$E$150"),$D2,INDIRECT("'"&'Ref Sheet'!$A$1:$A${DAY}&"'!$K$2:$K$150")))'
print(templateFormula)
```

expected result:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&'Ref Sheet'!$A$1:$A$13&"'!$E$2:$E$150"),$D2,INDIRECT("'"&'Ref Sheet'!$A$1:$A$13&"'!$K$2:$K$150")))
```

Actual Result

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&'Ref Sheet'!$A$1:$A${DAY}&"'!$E$2:$E$150"),$D2,INDIRECT("'"&'Ref Sheet'!$A$1:$A${DAY}&"'!$K$2:$K$150")))
```

Apply formula in this manner

```
        for t, CELLObj in enumerate(WS['E'], 1): 
            if t > 1:
                CELLObj.value = '=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&'Ref Sheet'!$A$1:$A${DAY}&"'!$E$2:$E$150"),$D{0},INDIRECT("'"&'Ref Sheet'!$A$1:$A${DAY}&"'!$K$2:$K$150")))'.format(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `format` on that string instead:

```
date = '09-13'
DAY = int(day[3:])
templateFormula = """=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&'Ref Sheet'!$A$1:$A${DAY}&"'!$E$2:$E$150"),$D2,INDIRECT("'"&'Ref Sheet'!$A$1:$A${DAY}&"'!$K$2:$K$150")))""".format(DAY=DAY)
```

Comment: Error code when doing that KeyError: 'DAY'

Comment: You're running all three lines, specifically the first two that establish the `DAY` variable?

Comment: Yeah and I get an error- I changed the int(day[3:]) to DAY = int(date[3:])
But the rest is copy pasted. This is due to an error in my original question in which it referenced a variable that isnt there in my example.

Comment: Oh wait, I'm blind. Try encasing the `templateFormula` in triple quotes so your quotes and double quotes don't get messed up.

`templateFormula = """=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&'Ref Sheet'!$A$1:$A${DAY}&"'!$E$2:$E$150"),$D2,INDIRECT("'"&'Ref Sheet'!$A$1:$A${DAY}&"'!$K$2:$K$150")))""".format(DAY=DAY)`

Comment: okay yeah that worked without even needing the .format at the end.
It just worked with my  {variable} after. 
Thank you!

Comment: @Huessy You should edit your answer with the change, not enter as a comment"

Comment: Using format won't help because the interpolation is the same as with f-strings.